# How to group a list of number together based on threshold using python while loop?

Tags: python

How to group a list of numbers together based on a threshold using python while loop?

For example, I have a list of numbers which are [1,2,3,2,5,6,2] and the threshold is 8. My expected output should be [[1,2,3,2], [5], [6,2]]. Since 5+6 is not equal to my threshold of 8 only 5 will be return. The function should continue till it finishes the list of numbers.

```
def group_numbers(num_list, threshold):
    i = 0 
    total = 0
    temp_list = []
    result_list = []

    while i < len(num_list) and total + num_list[i] <= threshold:
        total += num_list[i]
        temp_list.append(num_list[i])
        print(i)
        print(temp_list)
        i += 1
    else:
        result_list.append(temp_list)
        total = 0
        temp_list = [] 
        
    return result_list
```

my current code will only return [[1, 2, 3, 2]] and it will not continue. Not sure what is the problem here

Comment: Please, check [ask]. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do it, but that's what i have:

```
def group_list(lst, thresh):
    output =[]
    foo = []
    for i in lst:
        if (sum(foo) + i) > thresh:
            output.append(foo)
            foo = [i]
        else:
            foo.append(i)
    output.append(foo)
    return output
```